# GILEAD Website is not working. any link to developer guide or documentation?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gilead

Getting following error on hitting the [Gilead Website](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/)

Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: Unable to access /mnt/102/sda/1/8/noon.gilead/gilead/modules/CGExtensions/CGExtensions.module.php in /mnt/130/sda/1/8/noon.gilead/gilead/modules/Ballots/Ballots.module.php on line 38
ERROR: The CGExtensions module could not be found.

Fatal error: is_file() [function.is-file]: Unable to access /mnt/102/sda/1/8/noon.gilead/gilead/modules/MenuManager/lang/en_US/en_US.php in /mnt/130/sda/1/8/noon.gilead/gilead/lib/classes/module_support/modlang.inc.php on line 80

Comment: Gilead is not maintained since gwt introduced requestfactory.

Comment: Is request factory an alternate to Gilead

Comment: Yes, requestfactory is an alternative to Gilead.

Comment: i just studied about request factory. in this approach i have to manually create proxies for each POJO. i have to do a lot of work to implement this approach. any ways thanx.